# Python tree building with multiprocessing pool - no speedup

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to implement multi-threaded building of binary tree using multiprocessing Pool in python. The main idea is that having N hardware threads available, at the certain level I'd like to create each of the branches of the tree in separate thread. There are no data dependencies and each of the recursive calls works on its own data, so there are no concerns related to data races. I am familiar with GIL constraints, therefore I've decided to use multiprocessing pool:

```
pool = Pool(processes=4)
tree = Tree.createTreeMT(points, pool, 2);
```

The problem is i am not able to get any speedups. The function creating the tree looks like that:

```
def createTreeMT(points, pool, level = 2):
    # If there are no more points to process
    if len(points) < 1:
        return

    # Divide points into two groups:
    left_points = ....
    right_points = ....

    tree = Tree()

    if(level == 0):
        if len(left_points) > 0:
            leftPointsResult = pool.apply_async(createTree, (left_points))
        if len(right_points) > 0:
            rightPointsResult = pool.apply_async(createTree, (right_points))

        if(leftPointsResult):
            tree.left = leftPointsResult.get()
        if(rightPointsResult):
            tree.right = rightPointsResult.get()
    else:
        if len(left_points) > 0:
            tree.left = createTreeMT(left_points, pool, level-1)

        if len(right_points) > 0:
            tree.right = createTreeMT(right_points, pool, level-1)

    return tree


def createTree(points):
    # If there are no more points to process
    if len(points) < 1:
        return

    # Divide points into two groups:
    left_points = ....
    right_points = ....

    tree = Tree()

    if len(left_points) > 0:
        tree.left = createTree(left_points)

    if len(right_points) > 0:
        tree.right = createTree(right_points)

    return tree
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Is there a better way to perform such task in standard python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

apply_async returns an AsyncResult object, and when the main process calls "get" function on it, it will block until the result is computed. So, your main process is always blocking for each sub-task it is creating. Hence, no speedup!

One option is to use the "callback" option in apply_async. So you replace your following code:

```
if(level == 0):
    if len(left_points) > 0:
        leftPointsResult = pool.apply_async(createTree, (left_points))
    if len(right_points) > 0:
        rightPointsResult = pool.apply_async(createTree, (right_points))

    if(leftPointsResult):
        tree.left = leftPointsResult.get()
    if(rightPointsResult):
        tree.right = rightPointsResult.get()
```

with

```
if(level == 0):
    if len(left_points) > 0:
        leftPointsResult = pool.apply_async(
            createTree, (left_points),
            callback=lambda x: tree.left=x)
    if len(right_points) > 0:
        rightPointsResult = pool.apply_async(
            createTree, (right_points),
            callback=lambda x: tree.right=x)
```

The callback lambda function gets called once the result is ready. As you can see in the code, your tree will get filled properly in parallel as the results are computed by the pool-processes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I needed to do some workaround to bind `tree` to callback lambda, but it runs curreclty. It doesn't give me any speedup though - the code runs even slower.

Comment: How many points are you testing with? How many cores do you have on the machine where you are executing this?

Comment: The code runs or i7-6700 CPU with 4 cores and I am testing with ~50000 points, It might seem like a little, but consider a point being vector of integers of size between 1000 and 10000.

Comment: Are the points getting nicely split across processes? i.e., approx 50000/4 on each? Also how expensive is the operation to split the points into left and right sets?